# Matrix rank and concatenation

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Let $A_1$ be an $m \times n_1$ matrix, $B_1$ an $m \times n_1$ matrix  and $A_2$ an $m \times n_2$ matrix such that,

- $\text{Rank}(A_1)=\text{Rank}(B_1)=n_1$,
- $\text{Rank}(A_1:A_2)=n_1+n_2$, where $(A_1:A_2)$ is the matrix that concatenates $A_1$ and $A_2$.

Show that if $\text{Rank}(A_1:B_1)=n_1$ then $\text{Rank}(B_1:A_2)=n_1+n_2$.

Edit 1: The original question didn't make sense so I thought I'd modify it (rather than deleting and posting a new question. Not sure if this is the right thing to do or if it's good to have my original question). I also think I know the solution and will post later if no-one wants to post an answer.

Edit 2: Here's more context. The problem I'm working on has the assumptions:

- $\text{Rank}(A_1)=\text{Rank}(B_1)=n_1$,
- $\text{Rank}(A_1:A_2)=\text{Rank}(B_1:B_2)=n_1+n_2$

I need to have $\text{Rank}(A_1:B_2)=n_1+n_2$ but I can only impose conditions (preferably rank conditions) on the relationships between $(A_1,A_2)$, $(B_1,B_2)$, $(A_1,B_1)$ and $(A_2,B_2)$... obviously I would like the additional conditions to be as "mild" / general as possible.

The one I thought about was the additional assumption $\text{Rank}(A_1:B_1)=n_1$ but I'm now having problems proving that this additional condition implies that $\text{Rank}(A_1:B_2)=n_1+n_2$.

Comment: Just think about the number of linearly independent columns.

Comment: @user251257  All the columns need to be linearly independent so we want conditions under which $\sum b_i B_{1i}+\sum a_i A_{2i}=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $a_i=0,b_i=0$... we also know that $\sum a_{1i} A_{1i}+\sum a_{2i} A_{2i}=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $a_{1i}=0,a_{2i}=0$. Is this what you meant / right direction?

Comment: Consider $A_1 = e_1, A_2 = e_2, B = e_3$

Comment: @user251257 This implies $\text{Rank}(B_1:A_2)=n_1+n_2$... so if I'm understanding you correctly it's just the usual rank condition for a matrix to have full rank... and then $A_1$ has really nothing to do with the problem... so the question is not a good one at all!

Answer (score 1):

I'll show that with the assumption $\text{Rank}(A_1:B_1)=n_1$ then $\text{Rank}(B_1:A_2)=n_1+n_2$. From $\text{Rank}(A_1:B_1)=n_1$ and $\text{Rank}(A_1)=\text{Rank}(B_1)=n_1$, we can express each column of $B_1$ as 
$$
B_{1i}=\sum_{j=1}^{n_1} a_{ij} A_{1j} \qquad (*)
$$
so
$$
B_1 = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & \ldots & a_{1n_1} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n_11} & \ldots & a_{n_1n_1} \end{pmatrix} A_1
$$
Similarly we can express $A_1$ in terms of $B_1$ so we must have that the above matrix is invertible.

Now in order for $\text{Rank}(B_1:A_2)=n_1+n_2$ we need to show that the only solution to the following equation is 
$b_i=c_i=0$ for all $i$.
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n_1} b_{i} B_{1i} + \sum_{i=1}^{n_2} c_{i} A_{2i}=0
$$
Substituting in $(*)$, 
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n_1} \sum_{i=1}^{n_1} b_{i}  a_{ij} A_{1j} + \sum_{i=1}^{n_2} c_{i} A_{2i}=0
$$
Now we know that $\text{Rank}(A_1:A_2)=n_1+n_2$ so,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n_1} b_{i}  a_{ij}=0 \qquad j=1,\ldots n_1
$$
Hence,
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & \ldots & a_{1n_1} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n_11} & \ldots & a_{n_1n_1} \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ \vdots \\ b_n
\end{pmatrix} =0
$$
Now because the above matrix is invertible we must have $b=0$ so $\text{Rank}(A_1:B_2)=n_1+n_2$.